# How do I print out the constant names when printing all the constants in a C file using pycparser?

Tags: python, pycparser

I'm working on automating a tool that prints out all constants in a C file. So far, I have managed to print out all the constants in a C file but I can't figure out of a way to show the variable names they are associated with without printing out the whole abstract syntax tree, which has a lot of unnecessary information for me. Does anyone have any ideas? Right now, it will print out the constants, and their type. Here is my code:

```
from pycparser import c_parser, c_ast, parse_file

class ConstantVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []
    def visit_Constant(self, node):
        self.values.append(node.value)
        node.show(showcoord=True,nodenames=True,attrnames=True)

def show_tree(filename):
# Note that cpp is used. Provide a path to your own cpp or
# make sure one exists in PATH.
    ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True,cpp_args=['-E', r'-Iutils/fake_libc_include'])
    cv = ConstantVisitor()
    cv.visit(ast)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        filename  = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        filename = 'xmrig-master/src/crypto/c_blake256.c'

    show_tree(filename)
```

edit:
current output: constant: type=int, value=0x243456BE
desired output: constant: type=int, name=variable name constant belongs to(usually an array name), value=0x243456BE

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a brief example of the current vs expected output

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a more sophisticated visitor if you want to retain information about parent nodes of the visited node. See [this FAQ answer](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-ast-nodes-in-pycparser-have-parent-links) for an example.

That said, you will also need to define your goal much more clearly. Constant nodes are not always associated with a variable. For example:

```
  return a + 30 + 50;
```

Has two `Constant` nodes in it (for 30 and for 50); what variable are they associated with?

Perhaps what you're looking for is variable declarations - `Decl` nodes with names. Then once you find a `Decl` node, do another visiting under this node looking for all `Constant` nodes.